# how to send notification to android chrome browser using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, push-notification, web-push

I want to send push notification from node js to chrome browser of my android device.Is that possible? If so, how to achieve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you use SNS service for sending notification

Answer (score 1):

have a look at pretty module [web-push](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push)
You need to have GCM API key and VAPID key, which module helps you to generate for the first time.

```js
const webpush = require('web-push');

// VAPID keys should only be generated only once.
const vapidKeys = webpush.generateVAPIDKeys();

webpush.setGCMAPIKey('<Your GCM API Key Here>');
webpush.setVapidDetails(
  'mailto:example@yourdomain.org',
  vapidKeys.publicKey,
  vapidKeys.privateKey
);

// This is the same output of calling JSON.stringify on a PushSubscription
const pushSubscription = {
  endpoint: '.....',
  keys: {
    auth: '.....',
    p256dh: '.....'
  }
};

webpush.sendNotification(pushSubscription, 'Your Push Payload Text');
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Dima! I try your solution and it works in my desktop but not in chrome browser of my mobile. Any solution?

Comment: [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pushnotifications) too?